# Calculate the pressure required to stop a pipette (or pipe) from dripping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

Suppose that I have a pipette with a length of 10 cm that is filled with water, with a diameter of 1 cm.  If it is held vertically, how would I calculate the pressure required to stop any water from dripping out the end?

Comment: I will not give a complete solution to this problem since this seems like a simple homework problem. But here is a hint. what is the pressure at a depth d in a fluid?

Comment: Thanks - its not a homework question but I would imagine rho * g * h.  Or would the diameter factor in also?

Comment: Think it this way. The pressure at the bottom $P$ will constitute a force $PA$. So the force exerted  to avoid dripping at bottom should also be $PA$. The pressure will therefore be $PA/A = P$

Comment: So to answer you question @Chris Q, diameter won't factor in.

Comment: So is the equation p = rho * g * h correct?  Sorry, its been a few years since I had a class on this.

Comment: These hints appear to ignore the effect of surface tension - unless you mean to imply that part of the pressure to keep the liquid column in place is provided by the surface tension...

Comment: That was confusing me also.  Surely you have to factor in surface tension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a pipette, the liquid is usually kept in place by the surface tension. So there are several things:

- the weight of the column of liquid results in a pressure difference of $\Delta P = \rho g h$ between the top and bottom of the column
- this pressure difference will be supported in part by surface tension of the liquid, and in part by an atmospheric pressure difference (the pressure above the liquid is below atmospheric)

The pressure due to the surface tension depends on the shape of the drop, its size, and the surface tension of the liquid. The most pressure that the surface tension can generate happens when the contact angle is 90° - you have exactly half a drop hanging out of the pipette. In that case, the circumference of the drop (radius $r$) is $2\pi r$ and the total force is $2\pi r \sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the surface tension.

The pressure is given by the ratio of force over area, so $$\Delta P_{s.t.} = \frac{2 \pi r \sigma}{\pi r^2}\\ = \frac{2 \sigma}{r}$$

If the drop is not fully formed, the contact angle will be less than 90° and the pressure difference sustained by the drop will scale with $\sin\theta$.

I am ignoring the fact that there is some pressure difference from the top to the bottom of the drop. I am assuming (as is typically true for a pipette) that the drop diameter is small compared to the height of the liquid column.

Comment: Thanks Floris!  So for this problem I would just have to apply a back-pressure of (2 * 71.97 mN/m) / (5 cm) = 2.89 Pa, correct?

Comment: Not quite - with such a large opening, most of the back pressure will be atmospheric. Without the surface tension, you would support 10 cm of water with a pressure of 981 Pa. The surface tension will provide (2*72E-3)/(0.005) = 14.4 Pa f that pressure (careful with units! Half the diameter of 1 cm is 0.5 cm, not 5 cm). The remaining pressure is about 967 Pa. But I would not trust a 5 mm radius drop to be stable (plus it violates the "diameter much smaller than height" assumption and you would have to adjust the apparent column height for the amount of water in the drop).